# Adjust table column width depending on device type

Tags: css

In my css I have a table column which I'd like the width to be 20% of the screen when displayed on a PC but 80% if on a mobile or tablet. Can this be done?

I have a `@media` query but it doesn't seem to be getting picked up:

```css
@media (max-width: 40em) {
    .consent-cell--list {
        padding-top: 0.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100% !important;
        border-bottom: 0
    }
}

.consent-cell--list {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Could it be a setting or limitation with how/where I'm testing this? I'm viewing it in a Chrome browser after having toggled to mobile device in developer tools.

Comment: What do you want the breakpoint to be? (or do you really want to know if the user is on a mobile device, and how is that defined?) Once you know that you can try a media query and set the width in terms of vw units. Please put relevant code you have so far into your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @A Haworth, I have a `@media` query. Added some additional info to the question.

Comment: Put them the other way round. The second, more general one, is overriding the first (media selected) one. (this is why you should put a working snippet into your question....).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Transfer your `@media` query at the bottom of the page. C for Cascading means that whatever's at the bottom would override the same styles declared above them.

You can use `@media` queries to change your style on smaller screens and viewport dimensional units to set your container's width/height. I've added a snippet below to show this.

You can familiarize yourself on `@media` queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and on CSS units [here](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp).

```css
.consent-cell--list {
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 20vw;  /*this makes the container take 20% of the viewport's width*/
  background: red;  /*added this to make the container show*/
  height: 30px;  /*added this to make the container show*/
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .consent-cell--list {
    width: 80vw; /*this makes the container take 80% of the viewport's width*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="consent-cell--list"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Yong I added some additional info to the question.

Comment: @runnerpaul it is not taking effect due to it being positioned at the top, move it down to the bottom of your page to make it work.